# jQuery sync two input fields with .find?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to sync two time fields (which uses a popup date/time picker module in drupal), which is the **second "input"** in both main divs `start-date-wrapper` and `end-date-wrapper`.

The below works for the first input fields to sync the date fields

```
$('.start-date-wrapper').each(function(){
              var start_date_wrapper = this;
              $(this).find('input:eq(0)').change(function(){
                $(start_date_wrapper).next('.end-date-wrapper').find('input:eq(0)').val($(this).val());
              });
            });
```

But I my second one is not working, what am I missing? How can I target this correctly?

```
$('.form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value-time').each(function(){
              var start_time = this;
              $(this).find('input:eq(0)').change(function(){
                $(start_time).next('.form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2-time').find('input:eq(0)').val($(this).val());
              });
            });
```

```js
$('.start-date-wrapper').each(function(){
              var start_date_wrapper = this;
              $(this).find('input:eq(0)').change(function(){
                $(start_date_wrapper).next('.end-date-wrapper').find('input:eq(0)').val($(this).val());
              });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date-no-float start-date-wrapper container-inline-date"><div class="form-item form-type-date-popup form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value">
 <div id="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value" class="date-padding"><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value-date">
  <label for="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value-datepicker-popup-0">Date </label>
 <input class="date-clear form-text" type="text" id="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value-datepicker-popup-0" name="field_dateandtime[und][0][value][date]" value="21/04/2021" size="20" maxlength="30">
<div class="description"> E.g., 21/04/2021</div>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value-time">
  <label for="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value-timepicker-popup-1">Time </label>
 <input class="date-clear form-text" type="text" id="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value-timepicker-popup-1" name="field_dateandtime[und][0][value][time]" value="00:00" size="15" maxlength="10">
<div class="description">E.g., 03:15</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="date-no-float end-date-wrapper container-inline-date"><div class="form-item form-type-date-popup form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2">
  <label for="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2">to: <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <div id="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2" class="date-padding"><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2-date">
  <label for="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2-datepicker-popup-0">Date </label>
 <input class="date-clear form-text" type="text" id="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2-datepicker-popup-0" name="field_dateandtime[und][0][value2][date]" value="21/04/2021" size="20" maxlength="30">
<div class="description"> E.g., 21/04/2021</div>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2-time">
  <label for="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2-timepicker-popup-1">Time </label>
 <input class="date-clear form-text" type="text" id="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2-timepicker-popup-1" name="field_dateandtime[und][0][value2][time]" value="03:15" size="15" maxlength="10">
<div class="description">E.g., 03:15</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I also tried the first script and using `input:eq(1)` but i take this only works when inside the same div. Any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The time field uses a [popup date/timepicker](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_popup).

```
<div class="ui-timepicker-container ui-timepicker-standard ui-helper-hidden ui-timepicker-hidden" style="top: 1433px; left: 310px; height: 200px; width: 154px; z-index: auto; display: none;">
   <ul class="ui-timepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-menu ui-corner-all" style="width: 153px;">
      <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width: 153px;"><a class="ui-corner-all">09:00</a></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width: 153px;"><a class="ui-corner-all">09:05</a></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width: 153px;"><a class="ui-corner-all">09:10</a></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width: 153px;"><a class="ui-corner-all">09:15</a></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width: 153px;"><a class="ui-corner-all">09:20</a></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width: 153px;"><a class="ui-corner-all">09:25</a></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width: 153px;"><a class="ui-corner-all">09:30</a></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width: 153px;"><a class="ui-corner-all">09:35</a></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width: 153px;"><a class="ui-corner-all">09:40</a></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width: 153px;"><a class="ui-corner-all">09:45</a></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width: 153px;"><a class="ui-corner-all">09:50</a></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width: 153px;"><a class="ui-corner-all">09:55</a></li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" style="width: 153px;"><a class="ui-corner-all">10:00</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.index()` to get the index value of the `form-type-textfield` where input has been changed then pass this index value inside `eq("+here+")` to change same input value in other div.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.start-date-wrapper input').change(function() {
  var start_date_wrapper = $(this).closest(".form-type-textfield").index(); //get index of div
  //use same to change other input value
  $(this).closest(".start-date-wrapper").next('.end-date-wrapper').find('input:eq(' + start_date_wrapper + ')').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date-no-float start-date-wrapper container-inline-date">
  <div class="form-item form-type-date-popup form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value">
    <div id="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value" class="date-padding">
      <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value-date">
        <label for="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value-datepicker-popup-0">Date </label>
        <input class="date-clear form-text" type="text" id="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value-datepicker-popup-0" name="field_dateandtime[und][0][value][date]" value="21/04/2021" size="20" maxlength="30">
        <div class="description"> E.g., 21/04/2021</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value-time">
        <label for="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value-timepicker-popup-1">Time </label>
        <input class="date-clear form-text" type="text" id="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value-timepicker-popup-1" name="field_dateandtime[und][0][value][time]" value="00:00" size="15" maxlength="10">
        <div class="description">E.g., 03:15</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="date-no-float end-date-wrapper container-inline-date">
  <div class="form-item form-type-date-popup form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2">
    <label for="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2">to: <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
    <div id="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2" class="date-padding">
      <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2-date">
        <label for="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2-datepicker-popup-0">Date </label>
        <input class="date-clear form-text" type="text" id="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2-datepicker-popup-0" name="field_dateandtime[und][0][value2][date]" value="21/04/2021" size="20" maxlength="30">
        <div class="description"> E.g., 21/04/2021</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2-time">
        <label for="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2-timepicker-popup-1">Time </label>
        <input class="date-clear form-text" type="text" id="edit-field-dateandtime-und-0-value2-timepicker-popup-1" name="field_dateandtime[und][0][value2][time]" value="03:15" size="15" maxlength="10">
        <div class="description">E.g., 03:15</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Swati, using your approach instead works for the Date field but not the Time field unfortunatelly. Do I need to add/modify something to sync those fields too?

Comment: Its working for time field as well . Did you run above snippet and checked ?

Comment: yeah indeed it's working in the snippet, strange it's working only for the first field in drupal. I expected the same behaviour as in the end it's just html + jquery. Will have another look, thanks.

Comment: OK turns out that when manually entering the values into the time field and clicking outside of it then it does update on my site as well. I'm use a popup date/time picker, see updated post above and HTML example. Is there something we could adjust on the JS to make it work with that too? Thanks Swati.

Comment: i am not able to run them ..is that code somewhere online ? i just need to see html generated and how that part works .